# How to understand the Response Time Graph of jmeter results?

Tags: jmeter

Please explain how this graph will respond the results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your graph:

X/horizontal is the time of the execution as 16:05:50

Y/Vertical is the response time of each request in miliseconds

Each color is a different Sampler, as `PNM Profile View` in yellow

For example `PNM Profile View` sampler sent return answer in 16:07:40 after ~30 seconds

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user7294900 . But i want to know how all sampler will respond. for example User Dashboard after Login in red at the top of the graph.

Comment: It had the biggest response time up to 90 seconds at the start of the test. This reflect what actually occurred in your test

Comment: Thanks a lot. @user7294900   it really helps me alot to understand. That means this interface takes max number of time to load.